# Dart dio http get format array WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart, httprequest, dio

I am using dio to get json data from my wp rest api. In case of getting posting from wordpress, i get the following json format. So as you can see it is in array format. How can i change it to an object format so for example [0], [1],.. should be not in an array but in a list to be able to iterate through the map function. I have a blockade and cant figure it out really.

[{id: 6923, date: 2022-07-01T13:02:18, date_gmt: 2022-07-01T13:02:18, guid: {rendered: placehilder}, modified: 2022-07-01T13:02:19, modified_gmt: 2022-07-01T13:02:19, slug: news, status: publish, type: post, link: placeholder, title: {rendered: News}]

**Update**
My response from my http get function is type of 'Map<String, dynamic>' but i need it in 'List< dynamic >' to operate with my further processes.

Comment: "... should be not in an array but in a list...": what do you mean by this? Because type `List` is equivalent to "array" in Dart. Which part of the json do you want to format?

Comment: In my example above you can see that the response of my http get function is an array. I need it in a list of object format to iterate it through my map function or is there a transformation method to change this format [{},{},{},...] to this => {{},{},{},...} ?

Comment: It looks like your sample data is showing an array containing one JSON object representing the news endpoint. I noticed that the json inside the array [ is a bit malformed but otherwise you should be able to use the methods in my answer to pull out the object into a model class and otherwise store/work with the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

First I have to say that the data in the question is actually a List ( eg. `[{...}]` ) object with a portion of a single news post inside of it (the news post inside seems incomplete because it has no closing brace).

In Dart the JSON object is represented as a Map <String, dynamic> and there are methods on many dart model objects that transfer data to/from json (and also from maps). (*For more use cases with real code* - In your IDE search for a [Dart Data Class Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hzgood.dart-data-class-generator) plugin since it will help generate the methods in a model class)

Other examples of this can be found using a Google search. [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) is a simple one:

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
      };
}
```

There is also an interesting constructor on the List object that does exactly what you've asked. You can find the `from` constructor by referencing the [Dart api reference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-core/List/List.from.html).

```
const jsonArray = '''
    [{"text": "foo", "value": 1, "status": true},
    {"text": "bar", "value": 2, "status": false}]
    ''';
final List<dynamic> dynamicList = jsonDecode(jsonArray);
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> fooData =
    List.from(dynamicList.where((x) => x is Map && x['text'] == 'foo'));
print(fooData); // [{text: foo, value: 1, status: true}]
```